# Problem fetching data from Axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, axios

I'm creating a search that will print out results from the following API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users.

At this stage I just want the data to print out as search results. Currently, the "Failed to fetch results. Please check network" error message displays after *any* search.

Here's my search component:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      query: "",
      results: {},
      loading: false,
      message: ""
    };

    this.cancel = "";
  }

  fetchSearchResults = (updatedPageNo = "", query) => {
    const pageNumber = updatedPageNo ? `&page=${updatedPageNo}` : "";
    // By default the limit of results is 20
    const searchUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users${query}${pageNumber}`;
    if (this.cancel) {
      // Cancel the previous request before making a new request
      this.cancel.cancel();
    }
    // Create a new CancelToken
    this.cancel = axios.CancelToken.source();

    axios
      .get(searchUrl, {
        cancelToken: this.cancel.token
      })
      .then(res => {
        const resultNotFoundMsg = !res.data.length
          ? "There are no more search results. Please try a new search."
          : "";
        this.setState({
          results: res.data,
          message: resultNotFoundMsg,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (axios.isCancel(error) || error) {
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: "Failed to fetch results.Please check network"
          });
        }
      });
  };

  handleOnInputChange = event => {
    const query = event.target.value;
    if (!query) {
      this.setState({ query, results: {}, message: "" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ query, loading: true, message: "" }, () => {
        this.fetchSearchResults(1, query);
      });
    }
  };

  renderSearchResults = () => {
    const { results } = this.state;
    if (Object.keys(results).length && results.length) {
      return (
        <ul>
          {results.map(result => (
            <li>{result.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { query, message } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {/*Heading*/}
        <h2 className="heading">Live Search: React Application</h2>
        {/*Search Input*/}
        <label className="search-label" htmlFor="search-input">
          <input
            type="text"
            value={query}
            id="search-input"
            placeholder="Search..."
            onChange={this.handleOnInputChange}
          />
          <i className="fa fa-search search-icon" />
        </label>

        {/* Error Message*/}
        {message && <p className="message">{message}</p>}

        {/*Result*/}
        {this.renderSearchResults()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the code fails is in the target `searchUrl`.

A quick look and I can see that the `searchUrl` that is formed when the user types "Tim" is:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userstim&page=1
```

If you look at the HTTP request there's an 404 error:

```
GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/userstim&page=1
[HTTP/2 404 Not Found 18ms]
```

So, have in mind that you should always look into the original error message, you can of course present a different message to the end user, but this would have been helpful to you:

```
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error: ", error.message);
    if (axios.isCancel(error) || error) {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        message: "Failed to fetch results.Please check network"
      });
    }
  });
```

So, the reason why this is not working is the `searchUrl` pointing to an unexisting endpoint location. You can simply remove the `query` and see it in action!

```
const searchUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`;
```

[image]

So, fix the `searchUrl` and check the API documentation to understand what to do to filter by username.

It's out of the scope for the question but you can filter the data after the request to `/users` if a way to fetch by name doesn't exist...

```
data.filter(item => item.username === query)
```

Comment: @TimRobards happy that helped ;) So, remember... Errors are a good thing! Threat them well and handle any exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `this.cancel` to `undefined` when you initialise it, and after a search. Something like this:

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      query: "",
      results: {},
      loading: false,
      message: ""
    };

    this.cancel = undefined;
  }

  fetchSearchResults = (updatedPageNo = "", query) => {
    const pageNumber = updatedPageNo ? `&page=${updatedPageNo}` : "";
    // By default the limit of results is 20
    const searchUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users${query}${pageNumber}`;
    if (this.cancel) {
      // Cancel the previous request before making a new request
      this.cancel.cancel();
    }
    // Create a new CancelToken
    this.cancel = axios.CancelToken.source();

    axios
      .get(searchUrl, {
        cancelToken: this.cancel.token
      })
      .then(res => {
        const resultNotFoundMsg = !res.data.length
          ? "There are no more search results. Please try a new search."
          : "";
        this.setState({
          results: res.data,
          message: resultNotFoundMsg,
          loading: false
        });
         this.cancel = undefined;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (axios.isCancel(error) || error) {
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: "Failed to fetch results.Please check network"
          });
        }
        this.cancel = undefined;
      });
  };
```

But it's better to do it in one place:

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      query: "",
      results: {},
      loading: false,
      message: ""
    };

    this.cancel = undefined;
  }

  fetchSearchResults = (updatedPageNo = "", query) => {
    const pageNumber = updatedPageNo ? `&page=${updatedPageNo}` : "";
    // By default the limit of results is 20
    const searchUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users${query}${pageNumber}`;
    if (this.cancel) {
      // Cancel the previous request before making a new request
      this.cancel.cancel();
    }
    // Create a new CancelToken
    this.cancel = axios.CancelToken.source();

    axios
      .get(searchUrl, {
        cancelToken: this.cancel.token
      })
      .then(res => {
        const resultNotFoundMsg = !res.data.length
          ? "There are no more search results. Please try a new search."
          : "";
        this.setState({
          results: res.data,
          message: resultNotFoundMsg,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (axios.isCancel(error) || error) {
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: "Failed to fetch results.Please check network"
          });
        }
      })
     .finally(() => {this.cancel = undefined})
  };
```

If your environment supports [`Promise.finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).